# How to get entire page source using selenium and nodejs? driver.page_source is returning undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium-webdriver, npm, automation

Unable to fetch entire page source using selenium web driver with node js

I have tried using driver.page_source but in console, I get undefined as return

```
if(this.driver.findElement(By.id("ap_error_page_message")).isDisplayed()){
        console.log(this.driver.page_source);
    }
```

in results, I'm getting > undefined
I expect the output as source code of current webpage

Comment: Please post the context also, https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.

Comment: Also, findElement is an async function returns promise, you need to `then` it or do `await` on it.

Answer (score 0):

You could try innerHTML or outerHTML on the body or maybe even the html tag, like this:

```
const pageSource = await driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.css('body')), timeoutMS).getAttribute('innerHTML');
console.log('pageSource: ', pageSource);
```